# Looking for Optically isolated input board for Raspberry Pi

Tags: gpio, hardware

I am looking for a board with  that is able to take a ~12v signal and and send 3.3v to the Raspberry Pi.
I have drawn up a quick schematic of what the ideal board would be like (with screw terminals on each end).

[image: Schematic of ideal board]

The board also needs to be able to process input extremely quickly, so a relay wont work.

I can't seem to find any boards like this... is there anything out there?

Answer (score 3):

Not able to comment on the previous answer, I'll complete d3noob's answer here.
The Fiber Optics Kit from Jaycar is out-of-stock at the moment.

The following Kit seems to be a very similar (exact?) copy of it, and even cheaper :

http://i-fiberoptics.com/educational-detail.php?id=14200&cat=kits-projects&sum=1666

The datasheet is available on the linked page as a PDF.

[image: presentation of the Educational Communication Kit for Fiber Optics Communications]

You may also be interested in the Fiber Optics A/D Kit (Part Number: IF 545) available from the same shop, which includes "an on-board microphone for an audio analog signal source and a built-in 15 Hz oscillator for digital signals. It also has input connections for external analog and CMOS-compatible signals."
This 2nd kit seems to be more "stand-alone" than the first one.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a neat Fibre Optic Communication Kit [available from Jaycar](http://www.jaycar.co.nz/productView.asp?ID=KF4810%20&w=fibre%20%20kit&form=KEYWORD) (In New Zealand and I presume Australia). Probably a bit over the top of your requirements, but you never know.

Text from the description is as follows;

> This kit gives you a hands on introduction to fibre optics. It
>   contains all the components needed to build a fibre optic data link,
>   both transmitter and receiver, including one metre of fibre optic
>   cable and fantastic quality double sided plated-thry PCB's. A
>   fantastic 26 page booklet is included which gives you assembly
>   instructions, theory ( which is quit simple), a quick quiz and other
>   helpful information. When you have built this kit you will be able to
>   transmit and receive high speed data in serial format across one metre
>   of fibre optic cable. The transmitter is powerful enough to actually
>   transmit up to 16 metres!

[image]